# PHP error missing arguments twitter oauth

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I am using the function below

```
function GetTwitterAvatarOauth($oauthtoken, $oauthsecret){

$to = new TwitterOAuth($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $oauthtoken, $oauthsecret);
$content = $to->OAuthRequest('https://twitter.com/statuses/friends_timeline.xml', array('count' => '50'), 'GET');
$xml = simplexml_load_file("$content");
$imgurl = $xml->profile_image_url;
return $imgurl;
}
```

When i run the function, providing my token and secret (both valid) i get this;

```
Warning: Missing argument 3 for GetTwitterAvatarOauth()
Warning: Missing argument 4 for GetTwitterAvatarOauth()
```

Why would i get that error when i only require 2 arguments for the function?

Comment: Where is your invocation of that function?

Comment: <?

require_once('functions.php');
require_once('config.php');
require_once('dbconn.php');
require_once('twitterOAuth.php');

$oauthkey = "XXXX";
$oauthsecret = "XXXX";

GetTwitterAvatarOauth($oauthkey, $oauthsecret);

?>

Comment: GetTwitterAvatarOauth() is defined elsewhere maybe?

Comment: no, i wrote the function myself, no other ones like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might have GetTwitterAvatarOauth defined elsewhere.

Also, it looks like the $consumerkey and $consumersecret variables are not defined and this is likely to cause you problems also.

If those variables are global, try adding

```
global $consumerkey, $consumersecret;
```

before creating the TwitterOAuth object.